# StoreKit - Cannot connect to iTunes Store on Touch ID

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, itunes, storekit

Once in awhile, in Sandbox mode, Touch ID will have an StoreKit error. But if you supply your password instead of using Touch ID, it will work fine.

```
Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=1003 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x170462d80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store, SSErrorAllowBioAuthenticationKey=true}
```

That is the dump of the error. This only happens sometimes, but then when it starts happening, it never fixes itself.

A lot of our beta testers have had this problem, and we have not gone live in the app store yet. So it's scary to think that a lot of people won't be able to buy anything because of Touch ID error. I just hope we're not doing anything wrong on our end.

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation and it's delayed my launch!